# Andre Norton's story within Witch World series with Yareth the falconer as one of the characters novel identification

Tags: story-identification, andre-norton, witch-world

I am looking for a book's title of a novel by Andre Norton that one of the characters name was Yareth and his profession was falconry. I have read this book ages ago and now I cannot recall its title but I do know that it is within the [Witch World](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Witch_World) series.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Was it *To Rebuild the Eyrie*?

[This page](http://elwher.wikidot.com/falcon-law) about the later *Falcon Law* mentions that as the first place Yareth is seen.

Answer (score 1):

The short story "To Rebuild the Eyrie" by Sasha Miller from the first "Tales of the Witch World" collection edited by Andre Norton is the first story featuring Yareth.  He appears again in the novel "Falcon Magic" also by Sasha Miller, which is the second half of the book "On Wings of Magic- Witch World: The Turning Volume 3" edited by Andre Norton.